# If you dug to the center of the earth would you get stuck in an infinite gravitational pull loop?

Tags: gravity, earth

I was wondering what would happen if you dug to the center of the earth. Would you get stuck in an infinite gravitational pull loop, or would you just simply get torn in between the two pulls? Yes, I already know that you would burn alive, but this is theoretical.

Comment: How are you *crushed* between *pulls*?  Did you mean "pulled apart"?

Comment: This isn't worldbuilding, it's straight physics.

Comment: Here's  a video https://youtu.be/ZM9bRJpvRgI

Comment: @StephenG, while I think your comment certainly carries merit, I can see a worldbuilding element to it. The fact that the heat and pressure are being handwaved tells me that this could be related to a Core-style story for which the gravitational effects are being explored. As such, I'm happy to indulge the question a little more but Adrien, I'd recommend an edit which tightens up what you're asking just the same. While I'm not convinced it's off topic, I DO think it's unclear what you're currently asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you dig a hole crossing through the planet and you would jump in it from the surface, you would end up in the [famous case](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Mechanics/earthole.html) of the oscillation from one side to the other.

This would not be infinite, as over time the friction with air would slowly slow you down, until you would pretty much stop in the center of planet.

In the center of the planet you would experience almost no gravitational pull from the surrounding planet ([shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) docet), so no crush.

Comment: If there was no air then the fall would be infinite.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen It would not be an infinite fall, it would be exactly as described - an oscillating fall and rise, which is not the same as an infinite fall.

Comment: What would the atmospheric pressure (as a function of depth below MSL) be? If the hole is small (just big enough to fall down, or so), then the effects on the atmosphere above MSL would be negligible.

Comment: @user1008090 I don't think there would be atmospheric pressure down there as "atmosphere" implies a gas.  Earth's atmosphere has a scale height (where the pressure drops to 1/e) of about 8km.  That gives a pressure of almost e^800 atmospheres.  Google won't even touch the math.  In practice it will have become a supercritical fluid long before that.

Comment: @LorenPechtel, I expect the mantle and the core to have some degassing (I assume you mean e^-800?)

Comment: @LorenPechtel The pressure would be based off the mass of the air column above the center, as in $mgh$. But that won't scale linearly with $h$, since the force of gravity ($g$) changes with depth. But, yes, it will still be a very high pressure.

Comment: @kingledion Yeah, gravity will reduce it.  The point is it's so insane that the gas law won't apply anymore.